# <a href='javascript:...'>is submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have this code:

```
<a href='javascript:jQuery("#questionnaire").show();'>haha</a>
```

inside a form, for some misterious reason the form submits upon link clicking.
why is that so and how to prevent that?

p.s. this is a wordpress post

Comment: That code, alone, will not cause the effect you describe.

Comment: It is not submitting a form, the link is refreshing the page

Comment: Can you put the code of your form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to

`<a href="javscript:void(0);" onclick="jQuery("#questionnaire").show();">haha</a>`

Comment: thanks a lot, this did the trick!
for some mistrious reason, a href are taken as submit unless implicitly changed...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();//this will prevent the link trying to navigate to another page
        $("#questionnaire").show()
    });
});
```